# video streaming in angular 2

Tags: angular, video-streaming

How to play live streaming video seamlessly on UI in angular 2 ?
 My server sends chunks of video's in different url's.Is there any way to queue the url's received from the back end server and make them autoplay?

Comment: Take a look at the hls library and typings for angular if you are using .ts files, if not dashjs. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should try using HTML Video, set Video URL as 'src' attribute. This Video URL needs to transfer video content as stream of chunks data.

Comment: Suresh Kumar Ariya , backend server send's the video url's continuously, how to queue them one after the other?For a same video there will be multi urls.

Comment: @priyathamj.s, did you solve this problem? If yes, kindly post the solution.

Comment: No @Rai ,as of now I have only single video url.Later I will find a way to meet my requirement

Comment: @priyathamj.s My requirement is, Monitoring user activity via the web cam and send the live video to Admin. Admin can watch the live video of user activity. But, In user screen he/she don't know the recording. Any one can help me